# How can i save base64 to pdf file on Ionic 2 / cordova in the device's folders?

Tags: cordova, angular, pdf, ionic2, base64

I build an Ionic 2 app and I have to save PDF documents in base64 on the device's folders (for example in the folder 'download').

I already did that for an image with this plugin : 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-base64-to-gallery

It work well but now, I want to know if exists something like that for PDF files ?

I use Ionic v2.1.8.